# PHP dynamic checkboxes

Tags: php, dynamic, checkbox

I'd  like to display all roles from database as check-boxes and check the ones that the current user is already in.

**Question:** How can I check the check-boxes where the user is already in that role.

```
<?php
// DB QUERY: get role names
// ------------------------------------------------------------------
$get_roles = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT RoleName FROM roles")
or die($dataaccess_error);

$get_user_in_roles = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT RoleName FROM users_in_roles WHERE UserId = $user_id")
or die($dataaccess_error);
// ------------------------------------------------------------------

// user in roles
while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($get_user_in_roles))
{
    $user_in_role = $row2['RoleName'];
}

// echo out role names
while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($get_roles))
{
    $role_name = $row1['RoleName'];
    echo '<label class="label"><input type="checkbox" name='.$role_name.' class="checkbox">'.$role_name.'</label>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make `$user_in_role` an array, then change the statement inside the first while loop to `$user_in_role[] = $row2['RoleName'];` (this appends the role name to the array). Then, when echoing the checkbox, add this between `class="checkbox"` and the `>`:

`' . (in_array($role_name, $user_in_role) ? ' checked="checked"' : '') . '`

Answer (score 0):

```
<input checked='checked' type='checkbox' ... />
```

You can also `disable` input fields.

```
<input checked='checked' disabled='disabled' type='checkbox' ... />
```

Effectively making the check-box marked and disabled.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that disabling the checkbox would make that value not get POSTed, so depending on how you handle that it might lead to some weirdness (e.g., is lack of a value equivalent to not being checked?).

Comment: @Tom Smilack I generally have a hidden `input` with the expected value to keep form consistency. Nevertheless it's a good input. Thanks.

Comment: @Scott W. sorry by the lack of detail. Though you were looking for general guidance.