# Check the values of checkboxes with two queries

Tags: php, mysql

I want to populate check boxes from a table and mark them checked if they have records on another table.

I have two queries as shown below.

```
$hizmetler  = "SELECT * ";
$hizmetler .= "FROM hizmetler";
$sonuc = mysqli_query($conn,$hizmetler);
```

and

```
$id= $_GET['id'];
$query_hizmet  = "SELECT * FROM firmahizmet INNER JOIN hizmetler ON firmahizmet.hizmetID=hizmetler.hizmetID ";
$query_hizmet .= "WHERE firmahizmet.firmaID = $id";
$myresult = mysqli_query($conn, $query_hizmet);
```

I am trying to populate checkboxes with 1st query and add checked with 2nd query.

```
while ($row0 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($myresult)){

    while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sonuc)){ ?>
        <label for="chkbox"></label>
        <input id="chkbox" type="checkbox" name="<?php echo $row2["hizmetCSS"];?>" value="<?php echo $row2["hizmetCSS"];?>" <?php echo ($row0['hizmetCSS']==1 ? 'checked' : '');?> /><?php echo $row2["hizmetAdi"];
    }
}
```

But I think I am missing a huge point :D Tried to create a function and seek if myresult has overlapping values in sonuc, if yes I'd add checked but failed as well.

I inspected a similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074846/php-dynamic-checkboxes) with an good idea of

```
' . (in_array($role_name, $user_in_role) ? ' checked="checked"' : '') . '
```

but if the record does not have any row on firmahizmet table I get the following error;

> in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array

Any directions?

Comment: You are defeating the point of using MySQLi by throwing user input directly into your queries. Please use prepared statements.

Comment: @minitech can you explain what you mean? could not figure out that:(

Comment: Look up “prepared statements with MySQLi”.

Answer (score 0):

I have added an if statement to check if the array is empty or not and avoid problem, probably would be better ways to do it but it solved the issue.

```
while ($row0 = mysqli_fetch_array($myresult)){
    $user_in_role[] = $row0['hizmetAdi'];

}
    while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sonuc)){
        $role_name=$row2['hizmetAdi'];?>
        <label for="chkbox"></label>
        <input id="chkbox" type="checkbox" name="<?php echo $row2["hizmetCSS"];?>" value="<?php echo $row2["hizmetCSS"];?>" <?php
        if( !empty( $user_in_role ) )
        {
        echo (in_array($role_name, $user_in_role) ? ' checked="checked"' : '');
        }
        ?> /><?php echo $row2["hizmetAdi"];

    }
```