# dynamically assign values to checkboxes php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox, dynamic

New in php, older in MySQL.

I have a dynamically created table in php (colors from a table with an id and aname) with the names of the color and a checkbox for each. I have no value (now) for those checkboxes and **I cannot address them**.

I want to use those checked boxes to make a SELECT statement:

```
SELECT polish.*,colors.name 
FROM colors 
   inner join polish on colors.id=polish.colorid 
WHERE colors.name=.... 
   OR colors.name=.... 
 etc.;
```

something like that

```
            <table class="std">
                <tr>
                    <th>Colour</th>
                    <th>Include</th>
                    <th colspan="3">&nbsp;</th>
                </tr>

                <?php
                require_once("Includes/db.php");
                $result = polishDB::getInstance()->get_colours()?>
                <?php
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)):
                    echo "<tr><td>" . htmlentities($row['name']) . "</td>";
                    ?>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="col_list[]" value="ON"/></td>
                    <?php
                    echo "</tr>\n";
                endwhile;
                mysqli_free_result($result);
                ?>
            </table>
```

Comment: not able to understand .. what is the exact requirement ?

Comment: I think this has to be change, because I cannot identify the checkboxes, like: value=value1 for the first and value=value2 for the second row of the table

<td><input type="checkbox" name="col_list[]" value="ON"/></td>

Comment: add `id` as a value.

Comment: lolka_bolka
please be specific, how to do that? Write the code. Thanks

Comment: I find the answer here, thanks

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074846/php-dynamic-checkboxes?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

If your SQL is correct and returns correct rows so using your code you can do it just like You did it for a

> $row['name']

```
<input type="checkbox" name="col_list[]" value="<?=$row['columnname']?>"/>
```

the columnname is a column name from database which stores the colour

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign values to the checkboxes - use the ID from the returned rows from the database, e.g.:

`<td><input type="checkbox" name="col_list[]" value="<?= $row['id'] ?>"/></td>`

Once the form is submitted, the `$_POST` will then contain an array (called `col_list`) of the selected colour IDs.

If I understand the second part of the question correctly, you can use that array to create your SQL SELECT query. You can use the MySQL 'IN' syntax instead of multiple 'OR's.

```
$colourIds = implode(', ', $_POST['col_list']);
$query = <<<SQL
SELECT polish.*, colors.name 
FROM colors 
INNER JOIN polish ON colors.id = polish.colorid 
WHERE colors.id IN ({$colourIds})
SQL;
```